# #PHP i wanna do make the code better

Tags: php, sql

i try to make the code better and clean.

Working but looks bad. = > http://wklej.org/id/3275269/

Now i try to make it better.

```
$db = $this->database[GDB];

$message = '';
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT strUserID FROM USERDATA WHERE AUTHORITY=0');
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
    $this->Error('DB_ERROR');
    $db->getError();
    return;
}
else if($num_rows == NULL){
    $message = '<h3 class="error">List of Game Master is empty.</h3>';
}

$content = '';
while($result = $db->doRead()){
    $gm = $result['strUserID'];

    $query = $db->doQuery('select count(*) from CURRENTUSER where strCharID=?', $gm); 
    $row = $db->doRead();

    if($query == 1)
        $data['Status']='Online';
    else 
        $data['Status']='Offline';

    $content .= Template::Load('gmonline-1', array(
        'name' => $gm,
        'char_status' => $data['Status'])
    );

} //End while

$this->content = Template::Load('gmonline', array(
  'GM_LIST' => $content,
  'message' => $message
));
```

its not show error, but not showing all GM LIST.

Comment: Can you be more clear? the "looks bad" code is actually much cleaner than this. But still I have no idea what is that you want

Comment: Thanks for asnwer, because i want show Game Master List (Nick + status) with function while, but num_rows won't working like i want, because i not know how to using it

Comment: There is so much I don't know. What is the object `$db`? from the methods, I would say you're using the mongo DB, but then the queries are made in SQL.

Comment: thanks again for answer, http://wklej.org/id/3275281/ its method

Answer (score 0):

okay i did it. Well working

```
function Run()
    {
        $db = $this->database[GDB];
        $message = '';
        $num_rows = $db->doQuery("SELECT * FROM USERDATA ud LEFT JOIN CURRENTUSER cu ON (strUserId = strCharID) WHERE authority = 0;");
        if ($num_rows == -1)
        {
            $this->Error('DB_ERROR');
            $db->getError();
            return;
        }
        elseif($num_rows == NULL){
            $message = '<h3 class="error">List of Game Master is empty.</h3>';
        }

        $content = '';
        while ($row = $db->doRead())
            {
            if($row['strUserId'] == $row['strCharID'])
             $status = 'Online';
            else
            $status = 'Offline';
            $content .= Template::Load('gmonline-1', array(
                'name' => $row['strUserId'], 
                'char_status' => $status ));
        }
    $this->content = Template::Load('gmonline', array('GM_LIST' => $content, 'message' => $message));
    }
```